# jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named Mdb (ktor)

Tags: mongodb, hibernate, jpa, ktor, hibernate-ogm

I'm trying to create a JPA in **Ktor** that can access MySQL and MongoDB using the same application. The MySQL part is working fine. But I'm unable to connect with mongoDb. I'm getting the error message

`jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named Mdb`

It is unable to detect the MongoDB persistence provider. I'm attaching all my files below.

**persistence.xml file in */Kotlin/JPA/src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml*.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--    <persistence version="3.0" xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence">-->

<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">

        <persistence-unit name="pu">
            <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>


            <class>com.example.data.Student</class>

            <properties>
                <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>

                <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Students"/>
                <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
                <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.password" value="mynewpassword"/>
            </properties>
        </persistence-unit>

<persistence-unit name="Mdb" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence</provider>

    <class>com.example.data.Student</class>

    <properties>

        <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider" value="mongodb"/>
        <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.host" value="localhost:27017"/>
        <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.database" value="databasename"/>
        <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.create_database" value="true"/>

    </properties>

</persistence-unit>

    </persistence>
```

***Routing. kt file in plugins***

```
fun Application.configureRouting() {
        install(ContentNegotiation) {
            json()
    }

    routing {
        get("/") {
            call.respondText("Hello World!")
        }

        get("/jpa") {
            val a =  Student(3, "George", "Python")

      val emf: EntityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Mdb")
            val em: EntityManager = emf.createEntityManager()

            em.transaction.begin()
            em.persist(a)
            em.transaction.commit()
            println(a)

            call.respond(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Working")
        }
    }
}
```

**Entity class**

```
package com.example.data

import jakarta.persistence.Entity
import jakarta.persistence.Id

@Entity
class Student(
    @Id
    val id: Int,
    val name: String,
    val tech: String
)
```

**Similar to pom.xml in java application, I used **build.gradle.kts** for it.**

build.gradle.kts

```
val ktor_version: String by project
val kotlin_version: String by project
val logback_version: String by project

dependencies {
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-core-jvm:$ktor_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-locations-jvm:$ktor_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-content-negotiation-jvm:$ktor_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-jackson-jvm:$ktor_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-gson-jvm:$ktor_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json-jvm:$ktor_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-netty-jvm:$ktor_version")
    implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:$logback_version")
    testImplementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-tests-jvm:$ktor_version")
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:$kotlin_version")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-maven-plugin:1.2.30")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-maven-noarg:1.2.30")
    implementation("org.hibernate:hibernate-core:6.1.0.Final")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed-dao:0.38.2")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed-jdbc:0.38.2")
    implementation("org.ktorm:ktorm-core:3.5.0")
     implementation("mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.29")
    implementation("org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:3.12.11")
    implementation ("org.hibernate.ogm:hibernate-ogm-mongodb:5.4.1.Final")
    implementation("jakarta.transaction:jakarta.transaction-api:2.0.1")
//  implementation("javax.transaction:jta:1.1")
//  implementation("org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:6.0.0.Alpha7")


}
```

**Error message logs**

```
2022-07-22 18:29:58.431 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-1] TRACE o.h.j.b.i.PersistenceXmlParser - Persistence unit name from persistence.xml : Mdb
2022-07-22 18:29:58.431 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-1] DEBUG o.h.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider - Located and parsed 2 persistence units; checking each
2022-07-22 18:29:58.431 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-1] DEBUG o.h.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider - Checking persistence-unit [name=pu, explicit-provider=org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] against incoming persistence unit name [Mdb]
2022-07-22 18:29:58.431 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-1] DEBUG o.h.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider - Excluding from consideration due to name mis-match
2022-07-22 18:29:58.431 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-1] DEBUG o.h.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider - Checking persistence-unit [name=Mdb, explicit-provider=org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence] against incoming persistence unit name [Mdb]
2022-07-22 18:29:58.432 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-1] DEBUG o.h.jpa.boot.spi.ProviderChecker - Persistence-unit [Mdb] requested PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence]
2022-07-22 18:29:58.432 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-1] TRACE o.h.jpa.boot.spi.ProviderChecker - Checking requested PersistenceProvider name [org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence] against Hibernate provider names
2022-07-22 18:29:58.432 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-1] DEBUG o.h.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider - Excluding from consideration due to provider mis-match
2022-07-22 18:29:58.433 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-1] DEBUG o.h.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider - Found no matching persistence units
2022-07-22 18:29:58.434 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-1] TRACE o.h.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider - Could not obtain matching EntityManagerFactoryBuilder, returning null
2022-07-22 18:29:58.550 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-1] ERROR ktor.application - Unhandled: GET - /jpa
jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named Mdb
```

If there's anything needed please do mention. I will edit my question. Is there anything wrong in my logic? Where am I making the mistake?

Comment: Hibernate OGM is [no longer maintained](https://hibernate.org/others/). I doubt it's a good idea to start a new application based on it.

Comment: @yrodiere i saw that. This is part of a project. Do you have any other recommendations similar to Hibernate OGM?

Comment: I don't have any experience with alternatives, no, sorry. I guess you can find other NoSQL frameworks on google ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @yrodiere by NoSQL frameworks do you mean other databases?

Comment: I meant "libraries". JARs that allow you to interact with NoSQL datastores.

Comment: @yrodiere do you have any suggestions? The thing is I need to connect to both MySQL and MongoDB simultaneously.